# How to unpack a binary string consists of two bytes with a hint (LSB = version 0.01)

Tags: php, unpack

I'm working on unpacking a binary data for the first time, I'm doing it pretty fine but I have a part where I need to unpack two bytes with (LSB = version 0.01) (that's a hint written by someone I can't reach to), Could someone please explain that to me? and how I should do it in PHP, I have googled that first but I couldn't find anything useful out there.

```
<info>: 10 Bytes

offset  0 / 1 byte:  SV = payload structure subversion (0x01 -> version 1.00)
offset  1 / 2 bytes: HW = HW version (LSB = version 0.01)
offset  3 / 2 bytes: FW = FW version (LSB = version 0.01)
offset  5 / 1 byte:  DS = device status
offset  6 / 4 bytes: SN = 32-bit device serial number 


// My solution

$sensor->hw_version = unpack('v', substr($binary_data, 5, 2))[1]; // this giving me numbers like 110
```

Input is a base64 string, `otykgAFuAGUAAEwBQAMfCqMI6g3zA+UDBQR8AXEBiQEyAiQCPQKh/nb+SwBKAAA=`
expected output something similar to this:

```
CR = 0xEA69

MN = 0x19
SI = 0x80

SV = 0x01
HW = 1.10 (0x006E)
FW = 1.00 (0x0064)
DS = 0x05 (bit0 = 1: Request for response with settings, bit2-bit1 = 0b10: Watchdog reset occured before this transmission)
SN = 03401234

Sensor data:

S1  <battery>           = 2450 mV
S2  <solar>             = 1825 mV
S3  <precipitation>         = 360 (accumulative value in [0.1 mm])
S4  <air_temperature> average   = 15.62 degree C.
S5  <air_temperature> min       = 14.50 degree C.
S6  <air_temperature> max       = 16.02 degree C.
S7  <relative_humidity> average = 72.3 %
S8  <relative_humidity> min     = 71.0 %
S9  <relative_humidity> max     = 73.1 %
S10 <deltaT> average        = 2.55 degree C.
S11 <deltaT> min            = 2.12 degree C.
S12 <deltaT> max            = 2.89 degree C.
S13 <dewPoint> average      = 0.59 degree C.
S14     <dewPoint> min          = -1.21 degree C.
S15 <vpd> average           = 1.17 kPa
S16 <vpd> min           = 0.95 kPa
S17 <leaf_wetness>          = 15 min.
```

What else should I do?

Comment: We need example data. What your input is, what your output is, and what you expected it to be.

Comment: @Sammitch I updated the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`0x6E` is `110` in decimal, but `0x006E` depends on if you unpack it as big-endian, or little-endian. In this case you want *big*-endian, or the `n` flag to unpack.

```php
$enc_version = "\x00\x6e";
$unpacked = unpack('n', $enc_version)[1];
$dec_version = sprintf("%.2f", $unpacked/100);

var_dump(
    bin2hex($enc_version),
    $unpacked,
    $dec_version
);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "006e"
int(110)
string(4) "1.10"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually it's little-endian, should I use 'v' format instead?

Comment: Okay, I have used the format 'v' because I have little-endian, sprintf("%.2f",$this->uInt16(substr($binary_data, 7, 2)) / 100); but I'm getting 1 as a result.

Comment: Ah, I took the `0x006e` in the unpacked example a bit took literally. It _is_ little-endian in the base64'd data you've provided and `v` would be the correct flag. That said, the HW offset is 5 and is `0x6e`/`1.10`, the FW offset is 7 and is `0x65`/`1.01`. I couldn't tell you why you're getting `1.00` without seeing the `uInt16()` method's code. Either that, or you're mixing up binary blobs as the base64'd blob and the unpacked example are totally different.